# printing the key of map as string when you have only one key value pair in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a map with only one key value pair.

```
[A:B]
```

I want to print out the key of that map. I used

```
map.keySet()
```

which prints the key as an array.

> [A]

How can I print the `[A]` as a string like `A`?

I used

```
map.each { k, v->
    println k
}
```

but I want it to be in a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can just the first value from the list

```
map.keySet()[0]
```

Thanks

Comment: or longer, more functional: `map.keySet().first()`